# MySql Performance of Innodb with single large data file vs. multiple data files per table

Tags: mysql, innodb

InnoDB allows the option of using a single data file for everything or one data file per table by setting the following in your `my.cnf` file:

```
 [mysqld]
 innodb_file_per_table
```

Comparing 8 databases with 20 tables roughly with a  single ibdata file of 60G vs. a fairly evenly distributed 60G across the 160 individual data files in the one-per-table setup, does one setup have generally better performance than the other?  Are there any considerations that would favor one approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark it! We don't know your typical usage pattern or types of queries (Full scans? Narrow lookups based on index? Lots of updates or nearly read-only?).

`innodb_file_per_table` is easier to maintain — e.g. you can recover disk space after cleaning up and optimizing a single table; the default one-large-file will only grow.

Comment: Lots of reads and writes, but as far as ratio, probably 20-to-1 read to write.  We don't have a dedicated/experienced DBA and not sure how to benchmark, just hoping there might be a 'rule of thumb'.

Comment: benchmark just by running your regular traffic and measuring parameters youre interested [for some people it'll be avg execution time, for others number of concurrent requests per sec system can handle with response time up to x ms].